# Do not define components during render. React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM nodes and state

Tags: react-native

In the below code I am getting in line 1 can some one tell me the explanation and what should I change

```js
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: colorPalette.blue1, height: 80 },
    headerTintColor: "white",
    // headerLeft: () => <View></View>
    headerTitle: () => <Image source={appLogo} />, // line 1
    headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
  }}
  drawerContent={(props) => (
    <DrawerContent navigation={navigation} {...props}></DrawerContent>
  )}
>
```

I wanted to render a component in that?

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same issue declaring `<CustomDrawerContent />` component outside its parent component (DrawerMenuNavigator) like this:

```js
    function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerContentComponentProps) {
      return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
      );
    }
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerNavigationProps>();
    
    const DrawerMenuNavigator = ({}) => {
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}
          initialRouteName={DRAWER_MENU_NAVIGATOR.DASHBOARD_NAVIGATOR}
          screenOptions={{headerShown: false, drawerStyle: styles.drawer}}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            component={DashboardNavigator}
            name={DRAWER_MENU_NAVIGATOR.DASHBOARD_NAVIGATOR}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    };


/**EDITED: Passing props eg. colors from `useTheme()` hook */

    function CustomDrawerContent(props: (DrawerContentComponentProps & CustomColorsProps)) {
      return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
      );
    }
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerNavigationProps>();
    const {colors} = useTheme();
    
    const DrawerMenuNavigator = ({}) => {
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}
          initialRouteName={DRAWER_MENU_NAVIGATOR.DASHBOARD_NAVIGATOR}
          screenOptions={{headerShown: false, drawerStyle: styles.drawer}}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            component={(props) => DashboardNavigator({...props, ...colors})}
            name={DRAWER_MENU_NAVIGATOR.DASHBOARD_NAVIGATOR}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Hey there! How would you pass props then to `CustomDrawerContent` if you had to do it with this approach?

Comment: @jmonloop I just added an example